# Media Length of content that AudioStreamer is playing

Tags: audiostreamer, ios5

I am using [AudioStreamer](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer) by mattgallagher to stream MP3 from server to iPhone app. I know how to get the progress of playing content, but how can I get the total duration of the media?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `duration` property of the AudioStreamer object

```
AudioStreamer *audio = [[AudioStreamer alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%f", audio.duration);
```

Comment: My MP3 content is being streamed from server, instead of loading a file-based MP3. Therefore duration cannot be found via `audio.duration`.

Comment: When you say streamed, do you mean your loading it in another way as apposed to a URL directly to the MP3? If so, how are you streaming it? (I would like to learn)

Comment: Through streaming server via HTTP Live Streaming

Comment: Windows Media Services for Windows Server 2008 R2